# How set Oracle Weblogic oraInventory location?

Tags: oracle, weblogic

I've downloaded Weblogic Quick Installer from Oracles site (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/index.html).

I've set ORACLE_BASE and ORACLE_HOME to directories with write permission.

```
export ORACLE_BASE="/u01/app/oracle"
export ORACLE_HOME="/Users/victormarconi/Workspace/Java/Oracle"
```

Then: `java -jar Downloads/fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls_quick_Disk1_1of1/fmw_12.2.1.3.0_wls_quick.jar ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME ORACLE_BASE=$ORACLE_BASE`

Then the installer creates a directory in my home called oraInventory. I'd like to leave my home directory with personal files only... not files from an application.

How can I inform the installer to install oraInventory to a custom directory?

What are the best (standard) locations to set ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_BASE, etc ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you generate a file, for example `oraInst.loc`

With for example something like this content in it:

```
inventory_loc=/opt/weblogic12/OraInventory
inst_group=
```

And then when running the jar file you provide the parameter to use it:

```
java -jar wlinstall.jar -invPtrLoc /opt/weblogic12/oraInst.loc ....
```

Note the paths I use are just examples, use whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a 100% answer, as I've not found how to define the oraInventory for this installer (Oracle's Weblogic **Quick** Installer).

**BUT**, if you use [Weblogic Generic Installer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/index.html), the GUI will prompt for a location to store oraInventory.

Answer (score 0):

The installer documentation says, and I quote:

> Installation Inventory Setup   On UNIX operating systems, this screen
>   opens if this is the first time you are installing any Oracle product
>   on this host. Specify the location where you want to create your
>   central inventory. Make sure that the operating system group name
>   selected on this screen has write permissions to the central inventory
>   location.

There is more:

> Oracle Central Inventory Location on UNIX Operating Systems To find
>   the Oracle central inventory on UNIX operating systems, look for the
>   oraInst.loc file, which contains a pointer to the central inventory
>   location.

This is normally /etc/oraInst.loc